# Error passing variable from AJAX to PHP for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am getting an error when trying to pass a variable from AJAX to PHP for a MySQL query. I have tried hardcoding to make sure that the query works and it does, but when I try to dynamically pass the variable it is telling me the following "Error: Unknown column '$searchid' in 'where clause'". I am trying to send the value of a dropdown box to ajax to pull back data from a MySQL database. The returned data will then be put into 2 text boxes to be edited. Note: I am trying not to use the jQuery framework for this so I can get a better understanding of what the AJAX is actually doing.

AJAX code

```
function ajax_post(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var id = document.getElementById("editorginfo").value;
request.open("POST", "parse.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        alert (return_data);
        document.getElementById("orgeditname").value = return_data;
        document.getElementById("orgeditphone").value = return_data;    
    }
}

request.send("id="+id);
}
```

PHP Parse code

```
<?php
include_once('../php_includes/db_connect.php');

$searchid = $_POST['id'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orginfo WHERE id = $searchid';

$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_connect));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$orgid = $row["id"];

 $orgname = $row["orgname"];

 $orgphone = $row["orgphone"];

 echo $orgname, $orgphone;

}
?>
```

It's been a while since I have had time to work with code so I believe everything I used is still relevant. Also I know I havent put any sanitizing in yet, I wanted to make sure I can get the function working first, and I am the only one with access currently.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, your $searchid variable is not parsed. Use double quotes

Comment: @user574632 When I change that I get a new error "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM orginfo WHERE id = '$searchid'";  NOTE single quotes around variable, double quotes around the whole string

Comment: @user574632 Well that got rid of the SQL error, now it appears that there is no data returning which is strange since it works when hard coded. Is there a chance that AJAX is not throwing the correct variable to PHP?

Comment: possibly, why not echo out the ID in your php to check, or use console.log / alert in your js to test

Comment: @user574632 alert in JS shows the right id, echo in php isnt echoing anything though

Comment: @user574632 Thanks for you help in resolving the SQL error, if you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as correct for you and I'll keep working on the data passing issue. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate issue, you'll want to change this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orginfo WHERE id = $searchid';
```

Into this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orginfo WHERE id = $searchid";
```

Since your string is in single quotes, it is literally passing the string '$searchid' into the query rather than the value of `$searchid`.

Comment: When I change that I get a new error "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: It looks like `$searchid` is probably blank then. You'll want to verify that it has the expected value.